# Get all dependencies of a specific version of a Gem on RubyGems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Using RubyGems API, I need to request all versions of a gem (with api/v1/versions/[gem].json), and after that, for each versions, list all dependencies, like the result of api/v1/gems/[gem].json.

I looked, and the best way is to call api/v1/versions/[gem]-[version].json on a specific version, but it doesn't provide the dependencies for this version.

Is there another way to get all dependencies of a gem for a specific version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The best (and only way) is to use the dependency file of a gem, who list all dependencies of each version of the gem.
To get this file, it's necessary to call the dependency address of the API : http://guides.rubygems.org/rubygems-org-api/#misc-methods (the last one).

After that, this few line do all the stuff to get dependencies of a specific version :

```
  url          = URI("https://rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=#{gem_name}")
  dependencies = Net::HTTP.get(url)
  data         = Marshal.load(dependencies).each do |dependency|
    break dependency if dependency[:number] == gem_version
  end
```

Comment: Hi I am trying to build an API which can fetch all the dependencies of a gem  . Can you please guide me through the steps or post your gem dependency api code. Thanks.

Comment: Hi ! Well, the simplest way is to re-use the code I posted. You get all dependencies of all versions of a gem with the first & second line. It'll return you a file you need to load using Marshal class (it'll give you an array of objects representing the dependency) and then you just have to loop on this array to find the version of the gem you are looking for.
However, I can't post the code as it was a project for a company I'm no longer working for.